# Summing data in a dictionary grouped by category

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have a list in the form

```
World=[['spain','europe'],['germany','europe'],['china','asia'],['japan','asia']]
```

and a dictionary

```
Gdp={
     'spain':{2010:100,2011:101,2012:102},
     'germany':{2010:110,2011:111,2012:112},
     'china':{2010:120,2011:145,2012:152},
     'japan':{2010:105,2011:107,2012:109}
    }
```

I would like to output a dictionary that sums GDP by area and by year using
the World list to aggregate country by area:

```
AreaGdp={
       'Europe':{2010:210,2011:212,2012:214}
       'Asia':{2010:225,2011:252,2012:261}
       }
```

Comment: It would be better if you can ask where you got stuck instead of I would like...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects in place of regular `dict` objects. `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` which allows values to be updated very easily from other `Counter` objects.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> AreaGdp = {pair[1]: Counter() for pair in World}
>>> AreaGdp
{'asia': Counter(), 'europe': Counter()}
```

Now update the values of `AreaGdp` for each country in `World`:

```
>>> for pair in World:
        AreaGdp[pair[1]] += Counter(Gdp[pair[0]])
```

This yields:

```
>>> AreaGdp
{'europe': Counter({2012: 214, 2011: 212, 2010: 210}), 
 'asia': Counter({2012: 261, 2011: 252, 2010: 225})}
```

Comment: thanks for help i was a little lost because i tried to adapt a solution who suggested the use of groupby from itertools and itemgetter from operator [key,item for key,item in groupby(dict,key=itemgetter(key))] but in this case the area was part

Comment: ...of the dict in the form 'area':'europe' not from a list.